# Successful/Unsuccessful messages on MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I want to know what the easiest way would be to display successfully registered or unsuccessfully registered messages in MVC. I currently have an If statement which contains a lot of validation methods to register a user on our website. I want to show a Successfully registered message if the user is validated and registered successfully else an unsuccessfully registered message must display. I tried using the following code already :

```
TempData["alertMessage"] = "Congratulations, you have been registered successfully.";
```

and to call it to the view as follows :

```
if(null != TempData["alertMessage"])
   {
      <script type="text/javascript">
          alert("@TempData[alertMessage]");
      </script>
   }
```

but this is not working. Is there another work around which I can implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) You forgot the "" inside the alert around the alertMessage.

```
if(null != TempData["alertMessage"])
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
       alert("@TempData["alertMessage"]");
   </script>
}
```

2) Is the if() part at a position, where it is interpreted as C#-Code? If not, add an @ before the if.

```
@if(null != TempData["alertMessage"])
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
       alert("@TempData["alertMessage"]");
   </script>
}
```